# Xcode 5 not using phonegap's config.xml preferences

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a 3.1 phonegap project and since I cannot run it on an iOS device as of yet, I'm using Xcode 5 to run it for me on an iPad using iOS 6.

Problem:

The version I get to run on the device from Xcode does not use my config.xml preferences inside platforms/ios/MyApp/. Specifically I have tried the "Orientation" and "Fullscreen" preferences. Changing their values and rebuilding and rerunning has no effect.

What I have tried beside the default build and run in Xcode, is running `phonegap build ios` before opening the project in Xcode and then run the application without building. I have also tried doing that except by having the project open when I do `phonegap build ios`. I have tried changing the *.plist file in the same directory and that works.

I'd like not having to deal with the iOS specific *.plist if I can. Help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no Xcode 5.1. You probably mean 5.0.1.

Comment: Yep thanks. I will just name it "5" then.